# How to select all the check boxes in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a list where there are multiple select all buttons to for ng-repeat check boxes.
HTML code

```
<div class="col-xs-12"ng-repeat="items in testArray">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        {{items.brand}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-6">
        <button ng-click="selectAll()">select All</button>
        <div ng-repeat="i in items.form">
            <input type="checkbox"/>{{i.formName}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain little more? jsfiddle consisting current state of the code will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at code snippet given below , this will give you idea.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller('demoCtrl',function($scope){

   $scope.itemsArray = [{name:"Test 1",forms:[{formName:"xyz 1 "},{formName:"xyz 1 "}]},{name:"Test 2",forms:[{formName:"xyz 2 "},{formName:"xyz 1 "}]},{name:"Test 3 ",forms:[{formName:"xyz 3"},{formName:"xyz 1 "}]}];
  
  
  
  $scope.selectAll = function(item){
  
    for(var i =0;i < item.forms.length;i++)
      {
        
        item.forms[i].isChecked = true;
      }
  
  }
  
  $scope.removeAll = function(item) {
  
    
    for(var i =0;i < item.forms.length;i++)
      {
       
        item.forms[i].isChecked = false;
      }
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  <div ng-app="myApp">
    
    <div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
      
          <div ng-repeat="item in itemsArray">
      
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            
            <button ng-click="selectAll(item)"> select All </button> 
            
            <button ng-click="removeAll(item)"> Deselect All </button>  
            
              <div ng-repeat="i in item.forms">
              
                <input type="checkbox"   ng-model="i.isChecked"/>
                
              </div>  
            
            </div>
   </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: here you can get  the values of the checked check boxes to an array @Tharindu Senanayake

Comment: Thank you so much. You made my day

Comment: Dinesh Eventhough this helps me to select all the check boxes when I select a single one of the check boxes there is no way for me to get the value of that selected single check box. is there a fix for that

Comment: you should also  get single checkbox value , print out item object in console and see the details , there is "isChecked"  value is present in particular  object  (not for all  items ), for which you make selection.

Comment: Why not a single `function`? Example: `handleCheckboxes(item, flag)`, then in view: `<button ng-click="handleCheckboxes(item, true)">` and same for remove: `<button ng-click="handleCheckboxes(item, false)">`.

Comment: yes single function can be used nd also no need to pass flag simple add line as  item.forms[i].isChecked = ! item.forms[i].isChecked; so when its true it become false and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

you can try it.this example you can manipulate it according to your need
https://plnkr.co/edit/qD7CABUF9GLoFCb8vDuO?p=preview

```
 $scope.test=function(event){

     if(event.currentTarget.checked==true)
   { 
     var togglestatus=$scope.isAllSelected;
     angular.forEach($scope.options,function(object){

       object.selected=togglestatus

     })



   }else{
      angular.forEach($scope.options,function(object){

       object.selected=false

     })
   }
   }
```

html:

```
 <body ng-app="test" ng-controller="testctrl">
       <label>
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isAllSelected" ng-click="test($event)">SelectAll</label>

       <div ng-repeat="option in options">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="option.selected">checkbox</div>

      </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check [ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) directive. You need to add it to your input

`<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="i.isChecked"  />`

and then in selectAll() method set isChecked property on every item to true.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set a variable to `true` like this

```
ng-click="selectAll = true"
```

and then use the `ng-checked` directive to set the checkbox to checked when the expression inside is true

```
ng-checked="selectAll"
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12"ng-repeat="items in testArray">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    {{items.brand}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-6">
        <button ng-click="selectAll = true">select All</button>
        <div ng-repeat="i in items.form">
            <input type="checkbox"  ng-checked="selectAll"/>{{i.formName}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to get the values of the checked check boxes to an array. How can I do that? and thank you for the help

Comment: use `ng-change="toggle(i)"`which call a function in the controller that add `i` to an array

Answer (score 1):

Created a fiddle, showcasing your need for requirement "select all" - http://jsfiddle.net/deeptechtons/TKVH6/

```
//html

<div>
    <ul ng-controller="checkboxController">
        <li>Check All
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" />
        </li>
        <li ng-repeat="item in Items">
            <label>{{item.Name}}
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.Selected" />
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

//js
angular.module("CheckAllModule", [])
    .controller("checkboxController", function checkboxController($scope) {


    $scope.Items = [{
        Name: "Item one"
    }, {
        Name: "Item two"
    }, {
        Name: "Item three"
    }];

    $scope.checkAll = function () {
        if ($scope.selectedAll) {
            $scope.selectedAll = true;
        } else {
            $scope.selectedAll = false;
        }
        angular.forEach($scope.Items, function (item) {
            item.Selected = $scope.selectedAll;
        });

    };


});
```

Comment: Thanks Gopinath but I need to check the check boxes with in the nested ng-repeat . In the the above code I have  nested ng-repeats

Comment: so what the implementation would be same, grab the logic above thats it :)